# id property in yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

In yesod, we can specify the class attribute like so:

```
<div .myclass> ==> <div class="myclass">
```

Is there an analog for id? For example, something like:

```
<div #id> ==> <div id="id">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes; it has the exact syntax you guessed.

From the [Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates):

> There are two convenience attributes: for id, you can use the hash, and for classes, the period. In other words, <p #paragraphid .class1 .class2>.